# Minecraft One Player Per Config

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm going to try to make this quick basically i'm trying to make ONE config per player.

So basically when ever I call user.CreateUser(); if the user doesn't exist it registers there own config with there unique id as the name of the yml

My problem is that when ever I try to call user.CreateUser(); on the PlayerJoinEvent it shows a error and i'm not sure the **UUID u** shouldn't be returning null because it's inside a constructor or the other variables.

**Error**

```
[23:57:52 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to MCEnhanced v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.ja
va:310) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.jav
a:62) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.j
ava:502) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.j
ava:487) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:
296) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:156) [spigo
t-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:144)
[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:54) [
spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:231
) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java
:148) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:8
17) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:3
67) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:6
57) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
:560) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at crypted.mcenhanced.Handlers.UserDataHandler.CreateUser(UserDataHandle
r.java:46) ~[?:?]
        at crypted.mcenhanced.Mechanics.ConfigMechanics.CreateUser.CreateUser(Cr
eateUser.java:19) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0
_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0
_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1
.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.ja
va:306) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        ... 14 more
```

**CreateUser Listener Class**

```
public class CreateUser implements Listener {

@EventHandler
public void CreateUser(PlayerJoinEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    UserDataHandler user = new UserDataHandler(player.getUniqueId());
    user.CreateUser();

}
}
```

**UserDataHandler Class**

```
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.UUID;

public class UserDataHandler implements Listener {


     UUID u;
     File UserFile;
     FileConfiguration UserConfig;

    //UserDataHandler user = new UserDataHandler(player.getUniqueId()); // Make sure that you have the player.getUniqueId()

    public UserDataHandler(UUID u){

        this.u = u;

        File UserFile = new File("plugins/MCEnhanced/data/" + u + ".yml");

        YamlConfiguration UserConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(UserFile);

    }

    public void CreateUser(){

        if ( !(UserFile.exists()) ) {
            try {

                //Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "[MCEnhanced] Created a new File for " + player.getName() + "(" + player.getUniqueId() + ")");

                YamlConfiguration UserConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(UserFile);

                UserConfig.save(UserFile);


            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

               // Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[MCEnhanced] Could not create a new File for " + player.getName() + "(" + player.getUniqueId() + ")");

                //u.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "We could not create a file for your account!"); // THE PLAYERS CONFIG NEEDS TO BE CREATED!!!!!!!!

            }
        }

    }


    public FileConfiguration getUserFile(){

        return UserConfig;

    }

    public void setDefaultUserFile(){

        getUserFile().set("MCEnhanced.Info.IsInfected", false);

    }

    public void saveUserFile(){

        try {

            getUserFile().save(UserFile);

        } catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `CreateUser` method, you are referencing the `UserFile` *field* or instance variable of the current `UserDataHandler` object which is by default null. Your constructor for the `UserDataHandler` class does not instantiate this `UserFile` field and instead creates a local `File` variable inside that constructor which is then never used. The line...

```
File UserFile = new File("plugins/MCEnhanced/data/" + u + ".yml");
```

should be...

```
UserFile = new File("plugins/MCEnhanced/data/" + u + ".yml");
```

so that the `File` field is instantiated for that instance.

I would recommend using the lowerCamelCase naming convention to name your variables, fields and methods as well.