# Java Bukkit/Spigot per player configuration files

Tags: java, bukkit

I've been working on a Bukkit/Spigot plugin which uses separate configuration files, but with research done and many tests of other peoples' answers, I have not found a solution that wants to work for me. I have tried [Minecraft One Player Per Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508751/minecraft-one-player-per-config) and adapted it to my needs but it didn't work. Here's what I have:

```
private final String name;
private FileConfiguration config = null;
private final Plugin plugin;

public Files(Plugin plugin, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.plugin = plugin;
    config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(name));
}

public void create() {
    cfile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + File.separator + path, name + ".yml");
    if (!plugin.getDataFolder().exists()) plugin.getDataFolder().mkdir();
    if (!cfile.exists()) {
        try {
            cfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(cfile);
}

... set, get, etc methods
```

If I try to instantiate with

```
 Files f = new Files(plugin, "config");
```

I end up with errors when trying to get/set/etc or I end up with no errors nor any results. Anyone able to give me a hand with this? Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning:

```
config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(name));
```

This tries to load a configuration **without** an extension from the Bukkit main folder - not from the plugin folder. If you want to create the configuration later on, you should leave `config` with the null value.

```
cfile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + File.separator + path, name + ".yml");
if (!plugin.getDataFolder().exists()) plugin.getDataFolder().mkdir();
```

You have created a file to your DataFolder with an additional folder from the `path` variable. But you didn't have created the folder inside the DataFolder.
I would suggest:

```
File cfgFolder = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), path);
cfgFolder.mkdirs();
cfile = new File(cfgFolder, name + ".yml");
```

Your missing results could also be caused by not saving the configuration to disk:

```
config.save(cfile);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Thank you for pointing out that I was possibly trying to load a non-existent file. I just had to make a method to load the file into memory and you helped me with the directory problem, also!